# SKSpriteNode ScaleUpFrom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, sprite-kit, skspritenode

**Problem**

Scaling up a 2D image, scales up from the image centre point, however. I need it to scale up from a specific co-ordinate?

```
[backgroundImage setScale:rifleZoom];
```

My current technique to scaling up the image.

I need to scale up from centre screen as opposed to centre image

Now my way to place a rifle shot on the screen @ centre is this way:

```
CGPoint positionNow = CGPointMake(backgroundImage.position.x, backgroundImage.position.y);
CGPoint positionPrev = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

float xdiff = positionNow.x - positionPrev.x;
float ydiff = positionNow.y - positionPrev.y;

CGPoint newPositionOne = CGPointMake(0.5- xdiff, 0.5 - ydiff);
newPositionOne = CGPointMake(newPositionOne.x/rifleZoom, newPositionOne.y/rifleZoom);
```

Now this works perfectly no matter how much the image is scaled, however. I cannot seem to implement it into scaling the image up from the centre of the screen opposed to centre of the image.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried to change the position of the image before scaling it up. To the same same point make as `newPositionOne` However, this does not work or  not being done right.

**EDIT**

This scales and brings centre to screen centrepoint, or messes up completely. It's a little too off the cuff to make a decision exactly what it's doing.

```
CGPoint positionNow = CGPointMake(backgroundImage.position.x, backgroundImage.position.y);
CGPoint positionPrev = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

float xdiff = positionNow.x - positionPrev.x;
float ydiff = positionNow.y - positionPrev.y;

CGPoint newPositionOne = CGPointMake(0.5- xdiff, 0.5 - ydiff);
newPositionOne = CGPointMake(newPositionOne.x/rifleZoom, newPositionOne.y/rifleZoom);


double xPosition = newPositionOne.x / backgroundImage.size.width;
double yPosition = newPositionOne.y / backgroundImage.size.height;

CGPoint prevAnchorPoint = backgroundImage.anchorPoint;
backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(xPosition,yPosition);

double positionX = backgroundImage.position.x + (backgroundImage.anchorPoint.x - prevAnchorPoint.x) * backgroundImage.size.width;
double positionY = backgroundImage.position.y + (backgroundImage.anchorPoint.y - prevAnchorPoint.y) * backgroundImage.size.height;

backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(positionX,positionY);


[backgroundImage runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction scaleTo:rifleZoom duration:1.0] count:1]];
```

Comment: I've also now tried anchor points, however there anchor point must remain central to the image, as that is how the nodes are added. But when zooming I need it to focus on zomming central to the point the iPhone screen is centred at as opposed to the centre of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the anchor point property of the background node to change the point from which image scales. By default the `anchorPoint` is at (0.5,0.5). This indicates the center of the node. If you make the anchorPoint (0,0), then its moved to the bottom left corner.

> anchorPoint : Defines the point in the sprite that corresponds to the
>   node’s position. You specify the value for this property in the unit
>   coordinate space. The default value is (0.5,0.5), which means that the
>   sprite is centered on its position.

When you shift the `anchorPoint`, you have to adjust the background position again to counteract the movement due to changing the `anchorPoint`.

So you can use,

```
CGPoint xPosition = convertedPoint.x / background.size.width
CGPoint yPosition = convertedPoint.y / background.size.height

CGPoint prevAnchorPoint = background.anchorPoint
background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(xPosition,yPosition)

CGFloat positionX = background.position.x + (background.anchorPoint.x - prevAnchorPoint.x) * background.size.width
CGFloat positionY = background.position.y + (background.anchorPoint.y - prevAnchorPoint.y) * background.size.height

background.position = CGPointMake(positionX,positionY)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, the code you've provided appears to bring the centre of the image to the centre of my current anchor point whilst scaling, however. I need to scale it i.e expand from the centre of the screen point to give the "zoom" effect

Comment: why is `postionPrev = (0.5,0.5)`? shouldn't it be the centre of the screen converted to background coordinates?

Comment: it finds the difference between the backgrounds initial position to add nodes to the centre of the screen, which are then offset accordingly.

So with them lines above yours, they find the exact centre of the screen to where it is centred on the scaled image to place a node.

Comment: how is `0.5,0.5` the center of the screen?

Comment: when the image is originally loaded, the width/height are equal to the frame. then it is scaled.

Comment: I understand all that. but shouldn't the centre of the screen be `self.size.width/2, self,size.height/2` ?

Comment: I imagine it achieves the same thing. However, my code needs to find the centre of the image then convert it from the centre of where it is now, find the difference and add that difference to the image as it is scaled to add a node to that image. If that made sense, which it probably didn't..

Comment: I assumed that your requirement was that you move your rifle to different parts of the image, and when you zoom using the sniper scope the centre of the axis inside the sniper score should be static and the scaling should happen from that point.

Comment: that's exactly what I require, I think I see where you're going with this now :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70784/discussion-between-rakeshbs-and-user2415313).